# AngularJS - Change content in iframe or similar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qP53j/1/) to start with.

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/"></iframe>
<div id="test">click me</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( "#test" ).on( "click", function() {
    var iframe = $("#iframe").contents();
    iframe.find('#header').css('background-color', 'red');
    iframe.find('#header').html('My content');
});
```

**CSS**

```
iframe {
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
}
```

**Question**

- In the above example I can, with jQuery, edit the DOM content of an iframe without any problems.
- Can the same be done with AngularJS? Example?
- If not, can it be done with [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude)? Example?

Answer (score -2):

Try simply with

```
<iframe id="iframe"  src="./data-model.html" my-iframe></iframe>
var app = angular.module("myTestIframe", []);
            app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope){

            });
            app.directive("myIframe", function() {
                return {
                    restrict: "A",
                    link: function (scope,element) {
                        console.log(element.css('background-color', 'red'));
                    }

                }
            });
```

If you include jquery library you can also manage element with $(element)